# How to print a multi-page map with data from excel, MapPoint and VBA maybe?

Tags: excel, vba, printing, gis, mappoint

I have an excel file with information on my company's customers including addresses and latitude and longitude. I need to generate printed street maps showing a reasonable level of detail with pins showing the customers and bubbles displaying their info. Essentially I need to create something that looks like a Thomas Guide except with our customer info layered on to the street maps. I've been looking for DAYS and can't find any software to automate this process.

Currently I'm importing the data into Microsoft MapPoint, which does a fine job of generating the map with all necessary data. However MapPoint can only print what's currently displayed on the screen. So I'm stuck printing at a close zoom level, scrolling over, printing again, and continuing this process ad nauseum.

Is there maybe a way to automate this with VBA in MapPoint? I can find almost no info online about VBA for MapPoint.

Or maybe there's a piece of software out there that can do this at the push of a button. Printing a multi-page map of an area doesn't seem like that crazy of a demand.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would check out the Google Static Maps API. You can construct the URL using the fields in your spreadsheet, then call the URL to create the map. That depends on what you need to do with the map, however.

Comment: The problem currently isn't generating the map. It's printing it out over multiple pages. For reference I'm dealing with about 600 data points with about 5 pieces of metadata associated with each, spread out over an area larger than England. So a solution that could automatically ommitt map pages with no data point would also be hugely valuable.

Answer (score 0):

MapPoint's API is actually pretty well documented in the MapPoint help file, and most of the examples use VB6, which should be adaptable for VBA - you will need to add a reference to MapPoint's object model.

Yes you can automate the printing. Other approaches include copying to the clipboard; save to web page (and extract the Map's GIF image); or to use the GetPictureFromObject(). I recently wrote an article about using the latter from C# (it would be simpler from VB6 or VBA)

Answer (score 0):

You could also print to a very large PDF, see the tips from this newsletter -- 
http://www.mp2kmag.com/update/mappoint.newsletter/2013-02-18/

Here's a direct link to the article --

http://www.mapforums.com/print-large-multiple-sheet-maps-any-printer-27603.html

Eric